# Layout color change is not retained when App reopened

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-alertdialog

Alert dialog opens when TextView is clicked. Then if user selects any value, Layout color should change else not. This is working fine. But when I close and reopen the tab, color is not retained. How to retain the color even after the App is reopened.

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"    >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/genere"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/genere"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text=" Search Genre"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

OnClick:

```
Views mViews = new Views();
mViews.genere.setOnClickListener(this);
  public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.genere:
         ilist();
        break;
```

Java:

```
    public ArrayList<String> ilist() {

    final String[] ratings = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
    final boolean[] ratingschecked = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false};
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("checkedrate_i", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Select Ratings");
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(ratings, ratingschecked, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {

                   if(!ilist.contains(ratings[which])){
                       ilist.add(ratings[which]);

                    }

            } else if (ilist.remove(ratings[which])) {

                if(ilist.contains(ratings[which])){
                    ilist.remove(ratings[which]);
                }


            }
        }
    }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                for (int i = 0; i < ilist.size(); i++) {
                editor.putString("selectedratings" + i, String.valueOf(ilist.get(i)));
            }
            editor.putInt("size", ilist.size());

            editor.apply();



> if(!(ilist.isempty)){
>               //change gray color
>             }
>            else{
>              //Change white color.
>               }

        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    builder.show();
    return ilist;
    }
```

How to retain the color change made in list method even when app reopened.

Comment: If you wiling to retain the state of color event app is reopen then you have to save the color in either SharedPreference or DB. because these memory is persistent until you clear the data of remove the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the selected color in `SharedPreferences` and then retrieve it when creating the dialog.
Or simply check the `size` you saved in the `SharedPreferences` if it is greater than `0` then the user selected value and color should change otherwise not.